# Import: module not found by compiler, works with Visual Code, DefinitelyTyped

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, definitelytyped

I'm new to Typescript and I hope I'm missing something simple here. I've installed type definitions for a javascript library and get an error thrown by the compiler but can't seem to figure out what's going on. My editor is Visual Studio Code and I'm developing a react typescript project on a Mac. Here's the play by play.

I installed type definitions for 'keen-tracking' like so,

```
npm install @types/keen-tracking@2.0.0
```

Next, I added a few lines to 'src/vendor.ts' that looks like the following,

```
import KeenTracking from 'keen-tracking';

const keenTrackingCredentials = {
    projectId: 'xxx',
    writeKey: 'yyy'
  };

export const keenClient = new KeenTracking(keenTrackingCredentials);
```

Lastly, I import the keenClient in a component like so,

```
import {keenClient} from '../model/vendor';

const MyComponent :React.SFC<MemberProps> = props => {
    return <div>
        <Cover {...props} actionLabel="Label" action={function():void{ keenClient.recordEvent('pledge', {member: props.member.email} ) }} /> 
    </div>
```

I run my project with npm start and when I save the file, the compiler throws the following error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'keen-tracking' in '~/projectDir/src/model'
```

Visual Studio Code recognizes the link to the keen-tracking type definitions which looks like the following. I recognize that the typescript version is 2.0 and when I type tsc --version at a command prompt I see that version 3.2.2 is running, though I'm not positive that's the same version that Visual Studio Code is using.

```
// Type definitions for keen-tracking 2.0
// Project: https://github.com/keen/keen-tracking.js#readme
// Definitions by: Rui Ferreira <https://github.com/rui-ferreira>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
// TypeScript Version: 2.2

export default class KeenTracking {
    constructor(options: { projectId: string; writeKey: string; requestType?: string });

    recordEvent(
        collectionName: string,
        event: object
    ): Promise<{ created: boolean }>;

    recordEvents(events: {
        [collectionName: string]: object[];
    }): Promise<{
        [collectionName: string]: boolean[];
    }>;
}
```

I'd appreciate any pointers on where I can look next to get this resolved, my current thinking is that the definition is incorrect or maybe I need to debug the generated js files, though I haven't figured out how to do that just yet. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, it would be awesome if you can make a minimal reproduction that I can play with. You could change the TypeScript config to convert your code back to ES2015 so it's easier to debug the actual JavaScript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed types but not the module so install the module using below command and restart the app

```
   npm install keen-tracking --save
```

And also the way you installed types may not work

Try this too without version

```
  npm install --save @types/keen-tracking
```

Comment: I was wondering about this... and I no longer get an error. Keen tracking still isn't working for me though and now I'm working through getting the debugger running so I can see what is going on. I think this will eventually work out though. Thank you for your help!